# I want to create a custom, simplified ui for jbpm so that my customers can edit the workflow

Tags: jbpm

What is the best way to do this? 
Should I edit the web console to simplify down, or should I completely write my own interface?

Or is there possibly some sort of builder which I can do this with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the interface is simply disabling some features, you might be able to customize web console.  If the UI is rather different, I would suggest writing your own UI and use the remote API to get the information you want to show / send the commands you want to execute to.

We are working on what we call a customizable workbench, but currently it's only to add new screens, not yet customize existing screens:
http://blog.athico.com/2014/10/the-drools-and-jbpm-kie-apps-platform.html